# How to generate random code for Android application email verification

Tags: java, android, random, email-verification

I am writing a new Android application that require the users to register and the system need to send emails to give them a code for email verification.

The random code need to be a 6-digit code that consisting numbers with uppercase alphabet, for example, 6H94BA. I have done some research and still cannot find anything. How to do that?

Comment: This is commonly done in the backend - not the Android application itself. There would be no safety benefit.

Comment: It is really not clear what you are asking for. You put up an unclear description of a work flow; but as said - it is not even clear where you expect what to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
String randomCode = new BigInteger(30, random).toString(32).toUpperCase();
```

Comment: This is prefect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
 public static String getRandomString(){
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString().subString(0,5);
}
```